# ClientID Credentials for Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to find out how to get a ClientID and clientSecret to use with the Bigcommerce API.

Our website has to redirect an owner of a bigcommerce store to bigcommerce itself, so that they can grant us permission to query their sales data.

My understanding is that before doing this, we need credentials for OAuth, i.e. ClientID and ClientSecret, and that when our user grants us permission, we get back a token. 
The only problem is, I can't see where to get our credentials in the first place. Bigcommerce seems to want you to create an 'App', which it then suggests you place on their store. We already have a website, which is going to call the API behind the scenes. 
How do I go about getting ClientID, ClientSecret?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a developer account and then register a draft app which will provide a Client ID and Client Secret for you.

You can find the details in the Getting Started section here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/

Comment: Great, thanks for that - have got both ClientID and Secret ok.    I'm having trouble finding any examples of using the Bigcommerce API using .Net though - do you know where I can find a simple example of using oAuth with .net?  Do you do this using a Webservice? Thanks..

Comment: No. Sorry. I do not know .Net. Regardless, there are not a lot of in depth examples no matter what language you are using.